# How to hide an iOS numeric keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I'm using a numeric keyboard for input from a UITextField.  I noticed that Interface Builder has a return key property called "Done".  When I select "Done" under the return key options, I do not see that a Done button is created on the numeric keyboard.  I see the "Done" button on other keyboard types if I change it from a numeric keyboard to something else, but not when using a numeric keyboard.

- I want to create a "Done" button on the keyboard which will hide the keyboard when pressed
- I want to do this because of the amount of real estate the keyboard takes up
- I'm very new to iOS development, so the easiest and least convoluted way to accomplish this goal would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to implement this button to dimiss the keyboard?

Comment: I just did this on my own project and it works fine, the return button turns into Done button. Do you have any additional code that messes with the keyboard?

Comment: @8vius By default my numeric keyboard does not have a return button at all.  The bottom right button is a backspace/delete button and the bottom left is blank.  I have no code that manipulated the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical way of doing this is to assign a toolbar containing a button to the `inputAccessoryView` property of the text view.

Comment: Alright, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I've tried doing a little searching and seem to have come up short.  Would you be able to point me to a resource that covers this?  Thanks!!

Comment: Apple have a sample project in the developer library called *KeyboardAccessory*.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for all the help, and the high quality responses.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution online but it implies making an image for your done button: http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Also you can use the same method for getting the UIKeyboard view showed in the example and do the following, as per @Jim's suggestion:

```
UIToolbar *keyboardViewToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 206, 320, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *keyboardDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneSettingDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Number" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                         target:nil 
                                                                         action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                         target:nil 
                                                                         action:nil];



NSArray *barButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:spacer1, title, spacer2, pickerDoneButton, nil];
  [keyboardViewToolbar setItems:barButtonItems];
```

And add that view to the keyboard view.

Also, as a separate suggestion considering you're just starting out. On iTunes U you can download the Developing Applications for iOS Stanford class, it's a very complete course on iOS development, available for free on the iTunes Store.

Comment: I will definitely check that out.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        UIToolbar* KeyBoardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        KeyBoardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        KeyBoardToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[GlobalSettings GetTextBySelectedLocale:@"Done"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(DismissKeyBoard)],
                                 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                 nil];
        [KeyBoardToolbar sizeToFit];
        txtMessage.inputAccessoryView = KeyBoardToolbar;
    }
```

Where **txtMessage** could be `UiTextField` or `UITextView`.

```
-(void)DismissKeyBoard{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```